# Can I mirror my second and third monitors but not the first for a presentation?

Tags: display, mirroring

Assuming I have an external monitor plugged into my laptop and a projector - I now have three monitors.

I want to be able to see what is on the projector from the second monitor and leave the primary monitor for controlling the presentation.

My question is: **Can I mirror my second and third monitors but not the first for a presentation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it *exclusively* in Keynote, but it is indeed possible to mirror two of three displays.

[Open Display preferences, click the ? at the lower-right of the "Arrangement" tab of "Displays" system preference.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1482760?start=0&tstart=0) [To set up a combination of displays showing mirrored and extended desktop images, set up the three displays as an extended desktop, and then Option-drag a display icon onto another display icon to mirror the two displays.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13814?locale=en_US)

[Instructions with pictures.](http://create.pro/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Main-display-mirrored-and-3-seperate-monitors-OS-X.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Mojave (10.14; potentially also for earlier versions), do the following:

1) Make sure all displays are connect, you have System Preferences -> Display -> Arrangement open and 'Mirror Displays' is unchecked.

2) While holding the option key (!), drag-and-drop those displays on each other that you want mirrored.